# convert to string to json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a hash map and i was added 2 values into that map. After that i want to convert to json, but it is showing as string after converting json using jackson.
below is my code :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> attributes = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
metadata.put("type", test.getType().toString());
metadata.put("id", test.getId());
String metadataStr = metadata.toString();
String replaceStr = metadataStr.replace("=", ":");
values.put("metadata", replaceStr);
attributes.put("caption", values);
```

Here I am converting attributes to json like below :

```
String json = this.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attributes);

{
  "Test": {
    "metadata": "{id:f600b8fa-77cf-4225-ba42-39135909c7ce, type:test}",
   }
}
```

But i need like below :

```
{
  "Test": {
    "metadata": {
               "id":"f600b8fa-77cf-4225-ba42-39135909c7ce",
                "type":"test" }
   }
}
```

Can any one help me out this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating objects instead of placing strings in a hashmap, this way you have more (and easier) control over how you want your json to look

Comment: I totally agree with Laurens on this. You have an object, create a string from it, `"{id:f600b8fa-77cf-4225-ba42-39135909c7ce, type:test}"` since you need to replace a character, then put the string back into an object and JSON the object with the string still included. No where is the string taken back to an object. It would be better to do the "=" to ":" conversion before assigning them to objects.

Comment: can you please share any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

The root of cause is in type of values and this line:

```
values.put("metadata", replaceStr);
```

Need to have:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> attributes = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> values = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
metadata.put("type", test.getType().toString());
metadata.put("id", test.getId());
values.put("metadata", metadata);
attributes.put("caption", values);
```